# What does "Can you still" mean?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-departed

In *The Departed* (2006), Dr Madolyn shows her ultrascan report to Sullivan:

> Dr Madolyn: And they say that this little speck... is a penis.
>
> Sullivan: It's a boy.
>
> Dr Madolyn: Yeah, well, one usually follows the other
>
> Sullivan: **Can you still?**

They kiss and then the next scene occurs where Dr Madolyn
receives a letter addressed to Sullivan.

What does "Can you still" mean ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He's asking her if she's still able to have sex at this point during the pregnancy.

The kiss you see is the initiation of what ends up as them having sex.